# How do you copy feature classes into a new geodatabase in ArcGIS/Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to copy feature classes from a folder into a new geodatabase, but none of the files will copy into the new geodatabase. Why are they not copying through?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace="C:\\Users\\welchk\\Desktop\\HW6_data\\data\\"
env.overwriteOutput=True

#creating the gdb
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management("C:\\Users\\welchk\\Desktop\\HW6_data\\data\\", "t_6.gdb")

#creates a list using ListFeatureClasses function
fclist=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "polygon")

#uses CopyFeatures_management function to copy feature classes in the list to the data folder. 
for fc in fclist:
#Uses the describe function so below you can tell the basename
    fcdesc=arcpy.Describe(fc)
#copies the features using a function that saves the new feature class with the basename.
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc, "C:\\Users\\welchk\\Desktop\\HW6_data\\data\\t_6.gdb"+fcdesc.basename)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"...t_6.gdb" + fcdesc.basename
```

Your output file path is missing a delimiter.

If `fcdesc.basename = counties`, for example, the above code attempts to create `...t_6.gdbcounties` (and it'll actually make a shapefile) instead of `...t_6.gdb\\counties` (a feature class within the geodatabase).

Include the closing delimiter and it runs as expected:

```
"C:\\[directories]\\t_6.gdb\\" + fcdesc.basename
```